# How to place an svg element in the middle of the image width

Tags: html, css

Now svg icon is center to div.video-open-container when i remove. How to center svg upon img tag it is possible without remove div wrapper?

```css
.video-open-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

svg {
  position: relative;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="details">
  <img class="movie-img-details" [src]="getImageSrc()">
  <div class="video-open-container">
    <svg class="video-open" (click)='openDialog()' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M10 16.5l6-4.5-6-4.5v9zM12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.41 0-8-3.59-8-8s3.59-8 8-8 8 3.59 8 8-3.59 8-8 8z"/></svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear to me.

Comment: Why can't you center it in exactly the same way? What problem are you experiencing?

Comment: @ Arup Rakshit How to place an svg element in the middle of the image width

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please fix the missing image

Answer (score 1):

```
    .video-open-container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    svg {
      position: relative;
      width: 64px;
      height: 64px;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
 .details {
    margin-left: 50%;
    position: absolute;


}
```

```html
    <div class="details">
      <img class="movie-img-details" [src]="getImageSrc()">
      <div class="video-open-container">
        <svg class="video-open" (click)='openDialog()' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M10 16.5l6-4.5-6-4.5v9zM12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.41 0-8-3.59-8-8s3.59-8 8-8 8 3.59 8 8-3.59 8-8 8z"/></svg>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: try to add this   .details {
    margin-left: 50%;
    position: absolute;


}